# How can I inject an object instance into a spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a logging and configuration bean that needs to be created outside of Spring.  I know the "spring boot" way is to create [logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) and [configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) within spring, but how can I inject the logging and configuration beans into Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use a [SpringApplicationBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html) in combination with a parent [ConfigurableApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html) that holds the bean instances.  The beans are then available for injection as any other spring managed bean.

```java
StaticApplicationContext parent = new StaticApplicationContext();
parent.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("myConfigBean", new MyConfigBean());
parent.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("myLoggingBean", new MyLoggingBean());
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    .parent(parent)
    .sources(Application.class)
    .build();
app.run(args);
```